# Edit Dropbox files inside an Android WebView

Tags: javascript, android, api, webview, dropbox

How is it possible to read and edit a Dropbox file inside a WebView?

I read that there are [JS libraries](https://tech.dropbox.com/?p=345) for accessing Dropbox files.
In this case I don't know if they work, since some JavaScript operations are not allowed (neighter if my local HTML+JS files are in the `raw` folder), such as using [Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/).

I also know that Android allows to intercept a specific web page loading on a WebView, using a  code similar to the following.

```
browser.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView  view, String  url) {
        return false;
    }
    @Override
    public void onLoadResource(WebView  view, String  url) {
        String needle = "file:///android_asset/interceptedresource.html";
        if(url.startsWith(needle)) {
            url = url.replace(needle, "");
            // here I should access to my Dropbox file, through Dropbox API, and return it to the browser
            // ...
        }
    }
});
```

Is the latter case possible to implement?